# Pass command line to running application

Tags: macos, qt

I tried to search answer on my question with Google but didn't find any info. So what I need: I launch my Application Bundle. When application is running I type in Terminal `open /Application/MyApp.app --args <some_args>` and runned application got this `<some_args>`. Is it possible?

It is a Qt5 application. The best solve will be Qt5-native. But any Objective-C way also good.

Answer (score 0):

One approach for doing this is to have a communication channel between an already running instance of the application and the newly starting one.

For example the application could, at startup, create a `QLocalServer` and try to `listen()` on it.

If that works it is the first instance and can just continue with its startup.
If it does not, it can open a `QLocalSocket` to communicate with the already running instance and send its arguments over. The already running application can react to the incoming connection, retrieve the arguments and handle them.